# Send JWT Auth Token in httponly cookie to socket.io server

Tags: express, cookies, websocket, socket.io, jwt

I'm making a chat window in a project, and it needs authentication (to display profile info like name, avatar, etc.). I've already set up JWT authentication on both ends. Currently, the token on my client side is stored as an httponly cookie.

I'm setting up socket.io on my server side (Express) and I'm not sure how to get my JWT to the server. I believe I should only send it once on connection (correct me if I'm wrong) but i don't see any way to send it.

I'm also using React on the frontend if that is important, and socket.io-client for the frontend.

Comment: If it's in a HttpOnly cookie, your frontend will not be able to read the cookie and send it over a websocket. It needs to not be `HttpOnly`, or you need to use a different token.

Answer (score 0):

I was strugeling with this too but I think I found a solution

**Express Server**

Share the cookie options between your express cookies and the SocketIO Server constructor

```
import { createServer } from 'http';

import express from 'express';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';

export const cookieOptions: CookieOptions = {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'lax',
    secure: true,
};

const app = express();

app.get('/auth', (request, response, next) => {
    const authToken = 'uuid'; // <-- your secret

    // If I didn't set this, the cookie would expire before I could use it
    cookieOptions.expires = ! // type Date (e.g. now + 7 days)
    response.cookie('authToken', authToken, cookieOptions)
});

const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, { cors: corsOptions });

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    const cookiesString = socket.handshake.headers.cookie ?? '';
    const cookies = cookie.parse(cookiesString);
    const authToken = cookies.authToken ?? null;

    console.log({ authToken }); // <-- here is the auth token :D

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('message', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

**React Client**

`withCredentials: true` <-- this one fixed it for me

*Whether to include credentials (cookies, authorization headers,
TLS client certificates, etc.) with cross-origin XHR polling requests*

```
const App () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const serverHost = import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER_HOST as string;
        const socket = io(serverHost, { withCredentials: true });

        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('connected');
            socket.emit('message', 'Hello, server!');
        });

        socket.on('message', (data) => {
            console.log('Received message:', data);
        });

        return () => {
            socket.disconnect();
        };
    }, [])

    return <h1>Hello Socket IO</h1>
}
```

This is a very simplistic example I hope it helps!